# How to access a part of HTML element's Id in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I've a following HTML code for table:

```
    <table id="blacklistgrid_1"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
                              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
                              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="apnd-test">
    <tr id="reb1_1">
    <td><input type="text" name="pack[1]" id="pack_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="quantity[1]" id="quantity_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                              <td><input type="text" name="volume[1]" id="volume_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
    </tr>
                          </tbody>
<tfoot>
                        <tr id="reb1_2">
                          <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="products" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>


<td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
</table>
```

And I've following jQuery code on above table:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.products').click(function () {
        var new_row = $('#reb1').clone();
        /*Here I want to use the id as #blacklistgrid_1. As the there may be more than one tables present the ids could be #blacklistgrid_2, #blacklistgrid_3, and so on. So it should be dynamic not static for value 1*/
        var tbody = $('tbody', '#blacklistgrid');

/*And in this line too, I want to access the tr and t body of that table with specific id only*/
        var n = $('tr', tbody).length  + 1;
        new_row.attr('id', 'reb' + n);
        $(':input', new_row).not('.prod_list').remove();
        //new_row.find("td:eq(1)").html();
        $('<button style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>').appendTo( $(new_row.find('td:first')) );
        tbody.append(new_row);
        $('.delete').on('click', deleteRow);
       });
    });
```

I've written my requirement in form of commentin above code. So someone please help me in achieving this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you not simply get them by some specific class and iterate through via `each`?

Comment: What if you used a class `blacklistgrid` instead of sequential IDs? Then you could just iterate over the collection of elements matched by the class. (See also @intracept's comment)

Comment: @HawkenRives:No I don't want to use class. Only dynamic Id's I want.

Comment: Why not a class?  It's the simplest and most effective way of doing it.

Comment: But I really think you want classes. This is part of what they excel at. Is it a hard requirement that you can't use classes?

Comment: @HawkenRives:This is because there will be many tables with same class name and If I access the table by class name and want to add the new row to a specific table then the new row will get added to all the tables with same class. That's why I'm using ids.

Comment: You can choose the specific ID by the looks of it, so why can't you choose to add a specific class?

Comment: @intracept:Can you please put your thoughts in the form of answer. It would be better for me to understand.

Comment: @PHPLover That'd be why you'd want to iterate through the collection of tables matched by the class. That way, you're just working on one table at a time. This would require a reworking of your .products click function, but I think I'd be worth it. (Of course, I'm just an observer, so I probably care more about theoretical purity of code than you do, and–while I can kinda see what your aiming for, I can't quite grasp it.

Comment: @phplover: I guess what I'm really struggling with is, what is your question? What is the problem your code is having?

Comment: See the answer below from @Praveen as it probably does what you want.  You'll still need to iterate through the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do make your code, **`id`** starts with **`blacklistgrid`**

```
$('[id^= blacklistgrid_]') // here you can access all elements whose id starts 
                          // with backlistgrid_
```

and for accessing their specific children

```
$('[id^= blacklistgrid_]>td')
```

---

What others tried to explain in comments,

Here using `class` selector, you're going to access their id

```
$.each('.table', function () {  // iterate all the table elements
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    if (id === "blacklistgrid_1") {  // check for the ids
        //Perform ToDos
        var tds = $(this).find('td');
        // using tds perform its ToDos
    }
});
```